# How to show Google maps in DialogFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to show the location in dialog. So I decided to create a class and extends DialogFragment.

```
    public class MapMenuDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener  {
    private View view;  
    private ImageView ivClose;
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(STYLE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map, container, false);


        ivClose = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapBtnClose);
        ivClose.setOnClickListener(this);


        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.googleMap)).getMap();  

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.mapBtnClose:
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

But Here I am getting error in this line.

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map, container, false);
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Here I post My XML also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dim_10"
        android:background="@drawable/map_border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/googleMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mapBtnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting this error:

```
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at com.asrapps.travex.MapMenuDialog.onCreateView(MapMenuDialog.java:53)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
09-09 18:42:49.389: E/AndroidRuntime(19711):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the error you getting on that line?

Comment: Sorry For late reply. Herewith I have added the error log.

Comment: Are you sure that you got `null pointer` on line `view = inflater.inflate`? I think you might got on `.getMap` method, because it is deprecated. If so, please see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMap()).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because you're attempting inflate a fragment within a fragment. You would need to replace the map fragment and instead use MapView or a FrameLayout along with the FragmentManager.